# More concise CSS to select both current and child elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, bundling-and-minification

**Overview**

As part of a generic CSS framework, I have built a variety of controls. I wish to style them in the brand colours using generic and flexible classes, while keeping my CSS as small as possible.

Due to the number of elements and controls I need to style, the CSS file is crammed full of brand-centric styles. To implement the flexible structure I desire, it looks like I'll have to double-up (or triple-up) every single brand rule from

```
.brand.brand-red  .control.brand-control { color: red; }
```

into

```
.brand.brand-red  .control.brand-control,     /* Required */
.brand .brand-red .control.brand-control,     /* Required */
.brand  .brand-red.control.brand-control {    /* Useful */
    color: red;
}
```

This is less than ideal, as it would nearly triple the overall size of my CSS file, which I'm desperate to keep as small as possible. **Is there any way to write the second block of CSS smaller?**

Ideally I would be able to do something like this:

```
.brand & .brand-red.control & .brand-control { ... }
    /* or */
.brand / .brand-red.control / .brand-control { ... }
```

but I'm pretty sure nothing exists for this sort of thing yet, if it ever will.

**Summary**

I would like my generic CSS to be as small as possible, but still work for all of the following structures:

```css
/* COLOURS // BRAND COLOURS */
.brand.brand-red  .control.brand-control,     /* Required */
.brand .brand-red .control.brand-control,     /* Required */
.brand  .brand-red.control.brand-control {    /* Useful */
    color: red;
}

.brand.brand-red.control.brand-control {      /* Not Required */
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand brand-red">
    <div class="control brand-control">Test 1 // Required</div>
</div>

<div class="brand">
    <div class="brand-red">
        <div class="control brand-control">Test 2 // Required</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="brand">
    <div class="brand-red control brand-control">Test 3 // Useful</div>
</div>

<div class="brand brand-red control brand-control">Test 4 // Not Required</div>
```

**Reference:**

[W3Schools // CSS Selectors Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Nope...this is not possible with the current state of CSS. SASS etc can make it easier to write but it still outputs the same CSS.

Comment: ass i see. ( in this test ) everything you want to color...has a class `.brand-red`  . why not just use `.brand-red { color:red } ` ?

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for the suggestion! I thought as much, but was hoping there would be a way to minimise the output CSS. Still trying to convince my organisation to adopt a preprocessor as writing it is indeed a pain too.

Comment: @MihaiT Very good suggestion but the { color:red } was just an example. Each .control requires it's own set of branded styles. Wherever I set .brand-[variant], I want the brand styles for that variant to cascade down to everything below, as well as apply to everything on that level. I could just go with the first rule and enforce the .brand-[variant] being set on a parent element, but was hoping for more flexibility.

Comment: I Totally agree with @MihaiT, you should keep your css selectors as short and as focused as you can. all `.brand-*` classes will probably change the color/ font of the elements, and those definitions are inheritable by default anyway, so there is no real reason for the complex selectors. `.brand-red` will probably mean the same thing any time it is being used, so the hierarchy of it is redundant in most cases...

Comment: @RonenCypis .brand-red will not mean the same thing at all. Please read my response to MihaT. When possible I shall update the question to demonstrate. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is currently not possible using css selectors.

You can target:

- `.parent-class.another-parent-class`
- `.parent-class > .direct-child-class`
- `.parent-class .descendant-class`
- And of course a lot of other [cool options](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)...

But unfortunately you don't have an option for selecting a parent element, with another class that may be applied on it, OR on any of its descendants.

Sorry :-)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you are using .brand-red

```css
.brand-red {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="brand brand-red">
    <div class="control brand-control">Test 1 // Required</div>
</div>

<div class="brand">
    <div class="brand-red">
        <div class="control brand-control">Test 2 // Required</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="brand">
    <div class="brand-red control brand-control">Test 3 // Useful</div>
</div>

<div class="brand brand-red control brand-control">Test 4 // Not Required</div>
```